# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load andenginephysicsbox2dextension- Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to work with andengine in "**Android studio, not eclipse**" and im getting this error when i run the project.

```
9442-29483/com.makeinfo.andenginetemplate E/AndEngine﹕ MainActivity.onCreateScene failed. @(Thread: 'GLThread 2726')
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load andenginephysicsbox2dextension from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.makeinfo.andenginetemplate-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.makeinfo.andenginetemplate-1]: findLibrary returned null
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:355)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:525)
        at org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld.<clinit>(PhysicsWorld.java:35)
        at com.makeinfo.andenginetemplate.MainActivity.onCreateScene(MainActivity.java:71)
        at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity$3.onCreateResourcesFinished(BaseGameActivity.java:169)
        at com.makeinfo.andenginetemplate.MainActivity.onCreateResources(MainActivity.java:55)
        at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onCreateGame(BaseGameActivity.java:181)
        at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onSurfaceCreated(BaseGameActivity.java:110)
        at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(EngineRenderer.java:80)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1509)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
```

In some answers, someone said verify your build path settings but i didn't get what he exactly meant. I copied and pasted the library folders (which got "libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so" inside of them) into my main projects lib folder. What should i do to fix this problem. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated!

Here is the project folder setup:

[image]

**SOLVED**: 
http://geq-i.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-setup-andengine-in-android-studio.html

is referring to andengine
 is referring to andenginebox2dextension

Answer (score 6):

Its very simple. Follow this simple steps

**1)** Create a new folder called **"lib"** inside the libs folder of the **main app**.

**2)** Copy all the folders ie.armabi , armabi-v7a etc from **andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension/libs** folder, and paste in in the previously created **"lib"** folder in **main app**.

**3)** Now compress the **"lib"** folder as **"lib.zip"** and rename it to **"lib.jar"**.
this changes the **zip** extension to **jar**.

**4)** Finally add a line -- **compile files('lib.jar')** under dependencies{} in **Build.gradle** file of your **main app**.

**5)** Clean and build the project.

Comment: Hi! i ve done same procedure but still get error what do i miss here i dont get it.

Comment: Hey its solved by this steps..  i made silly mistake and forgot to add permission...

Answer (score 1):

Place your jni precompiled libraries (.so files) as per the following structure

```
app->src->jniLibs

    ->armeabi->your_libs.so

    ->armeabi-v7a->your_libs.so

    ->x86 ->your_libs.so
```

- Where app is your main app
- and jniLibs is the default folder which is picked up automatically (keep this exact folder name)

Comment: I did the steps you suggested exactly as they are but it still gives same error. Is there a chance that this problem has relation with build.gradle files? I have every module in my project, but it cannot load the library??

Comment: changing the folder name from "libs" to "jniLibs" did the trick :)! thanks!