# There is a UnsatisfiedLinkError when app run with PhysicsWorld on box2d in android stduio

Tags: android, android-studio, box2d, andengine

When I am running the code like this 
`PhysicsWorld physicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0,0),true);` the android sdk gives this error 
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMmem.png)

I added andengine, box2d libs and compiled these in build grade. my Build grade = `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/andengine.jar')
    compile files('libs/andengineaugmentedrealityextension.jar')
    compile files('libs/andenginelivewallpaperextension.jar')
    compile files('libs/andenginemodplayerextension.jar')
    compile files('libs/andenginemultiplayerextension.jar')
    compile files('libs/andenginemultitouchextension.jar')
    compile files('libs/andenginephysicsbox2dextension.jar')
    compile files('libs/andenginesvgtextureregionextension.jar')
            compile files('libs.jar')`.
My libs folder = [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGidO.png)
 i tried all of answer on internet i find but none of them didn't work.

What should I do 
thanks

Comment: You can follow my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34068202/2026280 ,  which addresses the same.

Comment: Thank you. This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the native libraries, which are some ".so" files. Try to find them where you found all those jars.